# How to prove this auxiliary lemma to Hawking's singularity theorem?

Tags: general-relativity, singularities

This theorem is number 44 of chapter 14 in Barret O'Neil's book "Semi-Riemannian Geometry (with applications to relativity)". The proof given, in particular the use of another theorem to justify the last passage, does not convince me. Here is it. How do I prove it?

**Lemma**

Let $S$ be a closed achronal spatial hypersurface in spacetime $M$. Let $q\in D^+(S)$, there is a geodesic $\gamma$ from $S$ to $q$ which has lenght $\tau(S,q)$, is normal to $S$ and does not have focal ponts of $S$ before $q$. ($\gamma$ is time-like aside for the trivial case $q\in S$).

**Notations**

$D(S)$ is the Cauchy development of $S$
$D(S)=D^+(S)\cup D^-(S)$, where, for example, $D^+(S)=\{q\in M:$ every past pointing inextensible causal curve from $q$ intersects $S\}$

$\tau(S,q)=\sup\{lenght(\alpha):\,\alpha$ is a causal curve from a point in $S$ to $q\}$

Now I know/I can prove that

-D(S) is open and globally hyperbolic

-There is a geodesic of the desired lenght normal to $S$

My question is this: how do I show that there are no focal points before $q$ (just because $q\in D(S)$)?

Comment: If there were a focal point $\tau(S,q)$ could not be the sup of the lengths as you wrote. Now I cannot check O'Neill's propositions, but I am quite sure that the point is that one.

Comment: I taught about that but it is still not clear to me how this could solve the question.

We CHOSE the maximal curve, if the presence of a focal point generated a lunger curve, we would have chosen the longer one... so are you implying that the presence of a focal point forbids the sup to be a maximum?

From the hypothesis we know that $J^-(q)\cap S$ is compact and globally hyperbolic, hence the function $x\mapsto \tau(x,q)$ takes a maximum on this set (compactedness) and there is a normal curve of desired lenght (hyperbolicity). How does the presence of a focal point disrupt this?

Comment: The idea is based on what happens on a sphere taking $S$ as the equator and $q$ as the endpoint of a northern meridian segment normal to $p \in S$ and having $p$ as the other endpoint. Assume that $q$ stays behind the north pole: The focal point. That segment ceases to be of minimal length from $S$. In Lorentzian geometry, for timelike curves minimal is swapped with maximal.

Comment: Sorry I cannot read O'Neill textbook and thus I cannot help you further. However that is an important property of geodesics, so it should be discussed in other books (e.g. Hawking-Ellis, Wald or Beem-Ehrlich-Easley...)

Comment: Well, well, I am starting to see something. So essentially what you are saying is:

[**Tentative of propostion**
In some sensible conditions (which?) the longest curve from an hypersurface to a point cannot be normal to that surface if there is a focal point among the normal curve.]

I will try looking in those books.

Comment: More or less it could work as follows. With your hypotheses, assume that there is a focal point $q'$ before $q$ along the causal geodesic normal to $S$ and joining $S$ and $q$. As a consequence there must be another causal geodesics $\gamma'$ reaching $q'$ from another point $p'$ of $S$ (and, in general non normal to it). The Lorenzian distance verifies the inverse triangular distance. Therefore the Lorentzian distance of $q$ from $p'$ is greater than the sum of the lengths of $\gamma'$ and the segment $q'q$ on $\gamma$.

Comment: There is always a curve maximizing the length of the causal curves joining two causally related points. So the length of $\gamma$ cannot satisfy the maximality property...Unfortunately,  I cannot check the hypotheses implying my statements, and in particular I do not remember the definition of focal point adopted by O'Neill...

Comment: A point $q=\gamma(r)$ is focal for $S$, where $\gamma(0)\in S$ if there is a Jacobi field along $\gamma$ for which $J(0)$  is parallel to $S$ and $J(r)=0$.

Comment: I forgot to include that O'Neil considers only P-Jacobi fields to define focality. There are just Jacobi fields above with the added condition that the 'near geodesics' too be normal to $S$. It can be a little tricky to put things perfectly in order, but your point is clear and I understand it now. I am very gratefull.